# Google place api, wants to get nearest location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Hello I want to search nearest location using google place api....

from https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types i have used types in my code for searching nearest places....

and the code is below

```
try {
     double radius = 5000; // 10000 meters
    // get nearest places
    nearPlaces = googlePlaces
                    .search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), radius,
                            "sublocality|sublocality_level_4|sublocality_level_5|sublocality_level_3|sublocality_level_2|sublocality_level_1|neighborhood|locality|sublocality");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return null;
}
```

but could not find nearest places

like if i am in "**San Diego, CA, USA**" then i want to get result like

**Gaslamp/Downtown,

Pacific Beach,

Ocean Beach,

Uptown,

Hillcrest,

Mission Valley,
Fashion Valley,

North Park,**

but instead of this i am getting only two value like

**Mission Valley East,

Serra Mesa**

so can any one help me what **type** i have to pass so i can get result like above instead of below result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous answer was deleted by a moderator for unknown reasons, I am re-posting with some more context as it is the currently the correct answer:

It appears you are trying return nearby geographical locations (anything from the [second list](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types#table2) in the supported place types). Unfortunately the Places API is not designed for this, it is designed to return a list of nearby establishments (anything from the [first list](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) in the supported place types) and up to two `locality` or `political` type results to to help identify the area you are performing a Place Search request for.

This is stated in the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResponses

> *"results" contains an array of Places, with information about each. See Place Search Results for information about these results. The Places API returns up to 20 establishment results per query. Additionally, political results may be returned which serve to identify the area of the request.*

If you type filter your Place Search request by a geographic location type like `locality` or `political`, you will filter out the establishment results and only be left with the  area identity results.

A Places API - Feature Request for returning nearby localities has been filed here:
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4434

If you believe this would be a useful feature please make sure your star the request to let us know you are interested in seeing it added.

Comment: Hello Chris if i want to find particular location can i use like that "Ocean Beach, San Diego, CA, United States" because if i tried to search with only "Ocean Beach" many places will be returns with named "Ocean Beach" so i have and  if i want to search like "Ocean Beach, San Diego, CA, United States" no places found :(

Answer (score 0):

double radius = 5000 is 5 Kilometers just over 3 miles.
If you increase the radius you should return more places

Comment: ya i have increased to 50,000 but still same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the distance to maximum 50Km and there are different types as follows:
establishment,lodging,spa,bar,church,place_of_worship etc.